# I want to upload a video using spring controller. Can you provide me the steps

Tags: spring, video, controller, upload

How to call a spring controller for video upload. Common multifile is not working . i have given enctype="multipart/form-data">

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam("fileUpload") CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {}

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Operation File upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
            <td>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></td>
                <td>Pick file #1:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pick file #2:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: "is not working" is a bit to less information for some usefull answer. Have you configured a MultipPartFilter? and Use `MultipartFile` instead of `CommonsMultipartFile` ... https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: No i have not configured multipart filter. i have configured like this.

Comment: When i use the above configuration as edited in the question working fine for image. only video uploading not working.

Comment: i provided all the information. With the above configuration not working for my video upload

Comment: You wrote: "When i use the above configuration as edited in the question working fine for image. only video uploading not working" - this sounds like a file-size-limit-problem. Have you tried a huge image and a small video?

Comment: <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
 </bean>

Comment: in dispatcher-servlet.xml i have given above configuration.

Comment: i am uploading a video having size 19.8 MB (20,775,195 bytes). In DB i am using Blob column in postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CommonsMult‌​ipartResolver` is configured to accept max round about 10MB (10.000.000 Byte) but you tried it with an round about 20MB file.

So increase the upload limit

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMult‌ipartResolver">

      <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes: 50.000.000 are almost 50MB-->
      <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.I am having one small doubt.  <img
                                          src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getUserImage"
                                          class="img-responsive" width="300" height="300" />.For to display image we are using above tag. To display video which tag we need to use?

Comment: response.setContentType("video/mp4/image/jpeg"); like this we need to try? and in jsp page what modifcations do i need to make?

Comment: @Ravi: to embedd an video in html, use the video tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp